# Similar controllers in different namespaces/scopes -- how to distinguish between them?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have 2 similar controllers in different scopes/folders:

```
MyApp.Controller1
MyApp.Namespace1.Controller1
```

and

```
  # mix phoenix.routes
  some_path  GET /             MyApp.HomeController1 :index
  some_path  GET /namespace1   MyApp.Namespace1.Controller1 :index
```

How can I refer to `:index` in _url or _path helpers in these controllers?

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to previous answer, but it was too long.
There is a second option to name the route in your `web/router.ex`:

```
scope "/namespace1" do
  get "/", MyApp.Namespace1.Controller1, :index, as: "namespaced"
end
```

Now you should be able to use `some_path(conn, :index)` and `namespaced_path(conn, :index)` without passing the module name.

Answer (score 1):

According to your `phoenix.routes`, these calls respectively:

```
some_path(MyApp.Endpoint, :index)
some_path(MyApp.Namespace1.Endpoint, :index)
```

See [routing](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/routing) chapter for details.